# Can shortcodes work in widget text?

Tags: wordpress, widget, shortcode

I used the following code in my functions.php file.

```
function cutOffDate() {  
return 'December 15, 2013';  
}  

add_shortcode('cutOff', 'cutOffDate');
```

When I add the shortcode to a page or post, it works fine.  But if I add the shortcode to text in a widget, all I get is "[cutoff]".

Can someone please point me in the right direction for solving this?  I know it's a nooob question (I'm a noob), but I have no clue where to even begin to look for a solution other than here.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this following line in functions.php

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Street, but remember I'm a complete noob.  Do I add it after the add_shortcode line?  Or do I replace the add_shortcode line?

Comment: Is there also a trick for inserting shortcode directly into the code of a .php page template?  I tried just putting in the shortcode but it didn't work.